# Customer Journey - Salesforce Event Data Injection Criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I should configure a Customer Journey using a Salesforce Event Data in Marketing Cloud. I should set purchase date equals Today as injection criteria, but i didn't have this possible choice in the dropdown list.

I can only put the "hard coded" date e.g. 07/03/2017.
Could you tell me if it is possible to enable other values in this dropdown list?

Comment: what is the datatype of purchase date field?

Comment: in service cloud the datatype is date

Comment: If you open Data Designer in Contact Builder and open the 'Sales and Service Cloud' Attribute Group, what is the data type assigned to your purchase date attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

### 1. Date Based Event

1. Rather than using the Salesforce Data Event, import your Salesforce object to a Data Extension using an Import Activity (and an Automation) or use Data Stream to import the data at a required frequency.
2. Add the DE created in step 1 to an Attribute Group, creating a cardinal relationship to the Contact Record
3. Use a Date Based Event and don't move the slider, so the contact enters the Journey based on the current date.

[image: date based event]

### 2. Decision Split

Use the Salesforce Data Event to inject all Contacts into the Journey, but eject them from the Journey at the first Activity by adding a Decision Split Activity to check if the Purchase Date is today, then route all other Contacts to an orphan branch so they exit the Journey after a 1 minute wait period.

[image: Decision Split]

Answer (score 0):

Have you already associated your DE within contact builder? To get the data extension fields available while setting the criteria, you have to check if your DE is correctly configured within [Contact Builder](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/)

I believe then you will be able to select the appropriate data as in the DE.

Answer (score 0):

Think people are missing the point a bit - sounds like you just want a dynamic NOW() value for comparing a date field when added as an entry requirement for a Salesforce Entry Event.

[image]

As far as I know it is not possible unfortunately.

An alternative would be to run queries against the synchronized Data Extensions that represent the desired Salesforce object, and have the date check as part of the query itself. You would then just set up a standard Contact Data Entry Event or Audience.